# Google Drive Resumable Uploads

Tags: google-drive-api

I am having trouble requesting the current status of a resumable upload. Based on the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#upload-resumable), the following request should return a Range header with the current range google has of my upload, but I keep getting the following response:

> Failed to parse Content-Range header

Here is my curl request:

```
curl -H "Content-Range: bytes */1443452365" -H "Content-Length: 0" locationUrl -X PUT
```

I have also tried `"bytes */*"` and `"*/*"` for the Content-Range header, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1.4TB??  What happens if you try a slightly smaller file :-)

Comment: tbh, I used different file sizes, that was just a bad example :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check the correct request format like the sample given below:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id":100}' http://localhost/api/postJsonReader.do
```

And, discussed in [other command-line tools](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/using_cURL#other-command-line-tools), when sending raw HTTP data, be aware that the **POST** and **PUT** operations will require computing the value for a `Content-Length` header. You can use the UNIX tool `wc` to compute this value. Place all the content of the HTTP body into a text file such as `template_entry.xml` (example used above) and run `wc -c template_entry.xml`. It is often difficult to debug if you accidentally use an incorrect value for the Content-Length header.

Lastly, you can request the status between chunks, not just if the upload is interrupted. If the upload request is interrupted, follow the procedure outlined in [resume an interrupted upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#resume-upload).

Comment: According to the google documentation the PUT command should have no data, hence Content-Length: 0. Also, I am getting this exact same issue when using requestjs and node, so that leads me to believe that it is not an issue with curl but possibly something else I am doing wrong.